# Randomly Querying a Postgresql table with Node/Express and working with the row data

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, handlebars.js

I have a table of 46 entries that I need to select one randomly, and then use the data from that one query and pass it off to my handlebars files. I'm not sure how to go about randomly querying the database, and I'm unsure how to actually return the row data for me to use in my handlebars files.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg').native;
var score = 0;
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Quiz Game', 
    });
});

//Make a random query here and return it in res.render
router.post('/', function(req,res) {
  pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL + "?ssl=true", function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM characters', function(err,result) {
      done();
      if(err) {
        next(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log(result);
        res.render('game', {
          result,
          diff: req.body.difficulty,
          title: 'Hiragana Quiz',
          currScore: score
        });//response.render
      }
    });//client.query
  });//pg.connect
});

router.get('/game', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Got URL");
    res.render('game',
        {
      title: 'Hiragana Quiz',
      diff: 'normal',
      currScore: score,
      name: 'Go select a difficulty',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/rvUlv4A.jpg'
});
});



module.exports = router;
```

When I log the query result to the console I do get data, but I am unsure how to use it in my handlebars files. I put it in the res.render as result because that's how my professor did it in one of the examples, but I don't know how to access the result properly.

```
{ command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 1,
  rows: 
   [ { id: 1,
       name: 'ka',
       img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Japanese_Hiragana_kyokashotai_small_KA.png' } ],
  fields: 
   [ { name: 'id', dataTypeID: 23 },
     { name: 'name', dataTypeID: 25 },
     { name: 'img', dataTypeID: 25 } ] }
```

game.hbs - Following my professor again, I put the {{#each rows}} tag and {{/each}} to encapsulate the data returned from result in index.js, but for whatever reason the code inbetween the {{each}} tags just doesn't show up at all.

```
<script src="/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("Loaded script");

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Verify user inputs on client side first
    $("#romaji").change(function() {
        console.log("Something changed!");
        if(!isValid()) {
            $("#error").html("Fix inputs!");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error").html("");
        }
    });
});

//If input contains anything but lowercase characters, error
function isValid() {
    console.log("isValid() called!");
    var rj = $("#romaji").val().search(/^[a-z]{1,3}$/);
    return (rj != -1);
}
</script>

<!--Title-->
<div align="center">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>

<!--Display Current Score, Difficulty, and current picture-->
<div align="center">
    <h2> Score: {{currScore}}/46 </h2>
    <h2> Difficulty: {{diff}} </h2>
    {{#each rows}}
    <h3> Char: {{name}} </h3>
    <img src="{{img}}">
    {{/each}}
</div>

<!--Form to submit answers-->
<div align="center">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="input" id="romaji">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="userInput">
    </form>
    <p id="error"> </p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to randomly query the database, and then return the data from the query for my handlebars file to work with?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to randomly query the database

I assume you run a recent pgsql server,

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 20
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-math.html

Comment: It returned this error for some reason

{ [Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "column"
LINE 1: SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 20
               ^
]
  severity: 'ERROR',
  sqlState: '42601',
  messagePrimary: 'syntax error at or near "column"',
  statementPosition: '8',
  sourceFile: 'scan.l',
  sourceLine: '1081',
  sourceFunction: 'scanner_yyerror' }